# Showing play button and time on each image

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to show play button and time on image I am having multiple images on single page.
My problem is that play button and time is showing only on top left corner but it should show appropriate time and play button on each image.
I am posting only one of the code here.

```
 <div>
         Good Song
    </div>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
   <pre>A.R. Rahman is the only Indian composer to have Academy Award to his credit. He has redefined popular music in India and given it an international face. Listen to some of his best compositions with this audio jukebox.

    Song Listing:
    00:02 - Rangeela Re by Asha Bhosle, Aditya Narayan
    05:35 - Taal Se Taal by Alka Yagnik, Udit Narayan
    11:42 - O Bhavre by Asha Bhosle, Yesudas
    17:50 - Telephone by Kavita Krishnamurthy, Hariharan 
    24:09 - Muqabala Muqabala by Swarnalatha, Mano
    29:30 - Tanha Tanha Yahan Pe Jeena by Asha Bhosle
    35:01 - Ni Main Samajh Gayi by Richa Sharma, Sukhwinder Singh
    39:24 - Jogiya Jogiya by Alka Yagnik, Udit Narayan
    45:03 - Piya Haji Ali by A.R. Rahman, Srinivas, Kadar Gulam Mustafa, Murtujha Gulam Mustafa
    51:42 - Urvashi Urvashi by A.R. Rahman, Shankar, Noel
    57:22 - Hai Rama by Swarnalatha, Hariharan
    1:04:04- Ishq Bina Ishq Bina by Anuradha Sriram, Sujatha, A.R. Rahman, Sonu Nigam</pre>
  </div>
 <img src="http://smsiland.com/img/video/small/002481eyrdqx3bo4_14_l7ntvw7ih6139019_sm.jpg" class="video-image"/>
 <img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/button_play.png"   class="play-video-image" />
   <span class="play-time">2:30</span>
```

My css are

```
.video-image{
    position:relative;  
}
.play-video-image{
    position:absolute; top:210px; left:60px
}
.play-time{
    position:absolute;
    top:230px; 
    left:310px;
    background-color:#e6e6e6
}
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: in plain English.....u want `play-image` and `time` the poster you have in the fiddle??

Comment: from what i can see is an image with a play button somewhere and a text 2:30 somewhere. What exactly do you want to do with them ?

Comment: I tried reproducing it on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e59gx/ and also changed a few things like adding a div for position relative to work. Tell if this is what you need

Comment: I want to show play button and time over image

Comment: @user3227094 : here u go => http://jsfiddle.net/sE5MK/

Comment: @NoobEditor what changes you made

Comment: @user3227094 : `top` and `left`...compare the css dude...its not much!!

Comment: @NoobEditor play-image and time going out of image if text is less or more

Comment: @user3227094 : that is bound to happen as the values set by you are in `px` and not in percentage....so your layout would not scale!!

Comment: @aelor your answer is perfect what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code:

```
<div>Good Song</div>
<div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"> <pre>A.R. Rahman is the only Indian composer to have Academy Award to his credit. He has redefined popular music in India and given it an international face. Listen to some of his best compositions with this audio jukebox.

    Song Listing:
    00:02 - Rangeela Re by Asha Bhosle, Aditya Narayan
    05:35 - Taal Se Taal by Alka Yagnik, Udit Narayan
    11:42 - O Bhavre by Asha Bhosle, Yesudas
    17:50 - Telephone by Kavita Krishnamurthy, Hariharan 
    24:09 - Muqabala Muqabala by Swarnalatha, Mano
    29:30 - Tanha Tanha Yahan Pe Jeena by Asha Bhosle
    35:01 - Ni Main Samajh Gayi by Richa Sharma, Sukhwinder Singh
    39:24 - Jogiya Jogiya by Alka Yagnik, Udit Narayan
    45:03 - Piya Haji Ali by A.R. Rahman, Srinivas, Kadar Gulam Mustafa, Murtujha Gulam Mustafa
    51:42 - Urvashi Urvashi by A.R. Rahman, Shankar, Noel
    57:22 - Hai Rama by Swarnalatha, Hariharan
    1:04:04- Ishq Bina Ishq Bina by Anuradha Sriram, Sujatha, A.R. Rahman, Sonu Nigam</pre>

</div>
<div class="video-image">
    <img src="http://smsiland.com/img/video/small/002481eyrdqx3bo4_14_l7ntvw7ih6139019_sm.jpg">
     <div class="play-video-image">
    <img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/button_play.png" class="play-video-image">
         </div>
        <span class="play-time">2:30</span>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.video-image {
    position:relative;
}
.play-video-image {
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:60px
}
.play-time {
    position:absolute;
    top:230px;
    left:310px;
    background-color:#e6e6e6
}
```